# Real time area chart application

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I have take following code from stackoverflow, When the application started running, dynamically area chart is updating, after few seconds application is hanging (i.e minimize, maximize, close buttons for the window are not working after increasing the window size). But area chart is updating.

```
package areachartsample;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class AreaChartSample extends Application {
    private static final int MAX_DATA_POINTS = 50;

    private Series series;
    private int xSeriesData = 0;
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number> dataQ = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number>();
    private ExecutorService executor;
    private AddToQueue addToQueue;
    private Timeline timeline2;
    private NumberAxis xAxis;

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
        xAxis = new NumberAxis(0,MAX_DATA_POINTS,MAX_DATA_POINTS/10);
        xAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);

        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setAutoRanging(true);

        //-- Chart
        final AreaChart<Number, Number> sc = new AreaChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis) {
            // Override to remove symbols on each data point
            @Override protected void dataItemAdded(Series<Number, Number> series, int itemIndex, Data<Number, Number> item) {}
        };
        sc.setAnimated(false);
        sc.setId("liveAreaChart");
        sc.setTitle("Animated Area Chart");

        //-- Chart Series
        series = new AreaChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        series.setName("Area Chart Series");
        sc.getData().add(series);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(sc));
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();

        //-- Prepare Executor Services
        executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory() {
            @Override public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                Thread thread = new Thread(r);
                thread.setDaemon(true);
                return thread;
            }
        });
        addToQueue = new AddToQueue();
        executor.execute(addToQueue);
        //-- Prepare Timeline
        prepareTimeline();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private class AddToQueue implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                // add a item of random data to queue
                dataQ.add(Math.random());
                Thread.sleep(50);
                executor.execute(this);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AreaChartSample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    //-- Timeline gets called in the JavaFX Main thread
    private void prepareTimeline() {
        // Every frame to take any data from queue and add to chart
        new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override public void handle(long now) {
                addDataToSeries();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void addDataToSeries() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { //-- add 20 numbers to the plot+
            if (dataQ.isEmpty()) break;
            series.getData().add(new AreaChart.Data(xSeriesData++, dataQ.remove()));
        }
        // remove points to keep us at no more than MAX_DATA_POINTS
        if (series.getData().size() > MAX_DATA_POINTS) {
            series.getData().remove(0, series.getData().size() - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
        }
        // update 
        xAxis.setLowerBound(xSeriesData-MAX_DATA_POINTS);
        xAxis.setUpperBound(xSeriesData-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Start taking pieces out until you have a minimal application, and then figure out (by trial and elimination) which piece breaks.

Comment: with out using executor service class, Thread, ConcurrentLinkedQueue , if i load area chart on button click it is working fine

Comment: Add them back *one at a time* until you identify what goes wrong. Also, this code is from stackoverflow? You should link to the original (does it work?)

Comment: You shouldn't be (imho) doing the background work in your same class where you are doing your GUI stuff...

Comment: Because of animation timer in prepareTimeline method, application window is hanging, if i remove animation timer, i can't add series data to area chart continuously. Then how to add data to area chart continuously without animation timer.

Answer (score 0):

I created an example for you. It uses a TimeLine for the chart update.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.SequentialTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class LiveAreaChartApp extends Application {

    private static int MAX_DATA_POINTS = 10;
    private static int Y_DATA_RANGE = 100;
    private static int TICK_UNIT = 10;

    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS = 100;

    private AreaChart.Series<Number, Number> series1;
    private AreaChart.Series<Number, Number> series2;
    private AreaChart<Number, Number> areaChart;
    private NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    private NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

    private SequentialTransition animation;

    private double nextX = 0;

    Random rnd = new Random();

    public LiveAreaChartApp() {

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis( UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

                // update chart data
                // note that we add one data point and remove one data point in this simple example. 
                // in a production environment you'd have to add multiple and remove multiple data points

                // add new points
                series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(nextX, Math.sin(Math.toRadians(nextX)) * Y_DATA_RANGE));
                series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(nextX, Math.cos(Math.toRadians(nextX)) * Y_DATA_RANGE));

                // remove points that shouldn't be visible anymore
                if (series1.getData().size() > MAX_DATA_POINTS) {
                    series1.getData().remove(0);
                }
                if (series2.getData().size() > MAX_DATA_POINTS) {
                    series2.getData().remove(0);
                }

                nextX += 10;

                // update using series 1 as reference
                // series 2 contains same amount of data; if it doesn't for your case,
                // you need to adapt this here and calculate the proper range
                List<Data<Number, Number>> data = series1.getData();
                xAxis.setLowerBound(data.get(0).getXValue().doubleValue());
                xAxis.setUpperBound(data.get(data.size() - 1).getXValue().doubleValue());

            }
        }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

        animation = new SequentialTransition();
        animation.getChildren().addAll(timeline);
    }

    public Parent createContent() {
        xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        xAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
        xAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
        xAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);

        yAxis = new NumberAxis(-Y_DATA_RANGE, Y_DATA_RANGE, TICK_UNIT);
        yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);

        areaChart = new AreaChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        areaChart.setAnimated(false);
        areaChart.setLegendVisible(false);

        series1 = new AreaChart.Series<>();
        series1.getData().add(new AreaChart.Data<Number, Number>(0d, 0d));
        areaChart.getData().add(series1);

        series2 = new AreaChart.Series<>();
        series2.getData().add(new AreaChart.Data<Number, Number>(0d, 0d));
        areaChart.getData().add(series2);

        return areaChart;
    }

    public void play() {
        animation.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        animation.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        primaryStage.show();
        play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your application, it is working fine when it was started. But if i click on maximize button of the application window, application is not responding. But area chart is updating continuously.

Comment: Then the problem is on your system. The code works just fine, even in a maximized state. What JDK are you using? Try to change the UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS to a higher value to see if it's a performance problem. Speaking of which, what does the Taskmanager performance chart show you? My current suspicion is that you system is too slow to handle the requirement.